# How to reroute sound from one hardware output to another using software?

Tags: linux, laptop, audio, hardware-failure

My notebook had some champagne spilt on it a long time ago.

As a result of this disaster the internal speakers went silent and don't make any sound, so I was forced to use external speakers via headphone jack output.

The interesting thing is that I  can still get sound from internal speakers when I launch some games (`Starcraft 2`, `Dungeon Defenders`) and when they are still in the background I have working speakers in all other system.

**Explanations about sound:**

When starcraft2 or Dungeon Defenders not launched my speakers are dead. No sound, no bass - nothing. 
If they launched, i have speakers *magically* working in system, even if i alt+tab from application. In short - this two games running, even in background, my speakers work.

It is really look like some software problem but - this problem active in Windows8, Windows Vista and Ubuntu 12.04

So questions is - How can I get information about sound "routing" inside system?

Maybe some Linux utilities can help me? Currently I am using Windows 8, but "problem" began when I was running Windows Vista.

**Additional information**

Screenshot of CP -> Sound -> Playback ([list of playback devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbptQ.jpg)). Level on dynamics is from youtube playing in background. Speakers do not play this sound, but as you can see system detects incoming signal and level.

I do not have a sound from external speakers(2nd device in Playback tab) when internal works in Starcraft2 or DD.

Sound type is stereo in both games.

Eventually when i close games - no sound from internal speakers.

This is so like routing problems in ip, but with hardware, but i cant find programs or methods to display where sound is routed when game started.

Comment: Can you explain better when you say "internal speakers don't make any sound" and then you also say "I can still get sound from internal speakers"? Can you successfully recreate this scenario too?

Comment: I can recreate this scenario. Every time i launch this two games i got sound from speakers. They running in background - i still got sound from speakers. If by some method i can capture what happens in systems when these two games launch, then i maybe can fix my speakers. But as today no luck. I dont really know how launch process can be protocoled.

Comment: What is your primary goal? Do you want to be able "fix" your speakers? Because your question doesn't sound like that's the primary focus. If you have the same symptoms on different operating systems, it is unlikely to be a pure software issue (unless the vendor supplied the drivers for all these operating systems). I would suggest looking into areas were hardware and software meet. Like when the speakers are disabled once you plug in headphones.

Comment: (1) Does your external speaker have sounds when you playing SC2 and DD? (2) What is the sound settings in games? (DB? 5.1?) (3) Can you post a screen shot of `Control Panel`-> `Sound` -> `Playback` tab. (4) Games and many audio software can choose their own output device, maybe your internal speaker is not the default, but the program are able to reach it some how.

Comment: @JohnSiu (1) no (2) stereo (3) posted in answer (4) I tried to changing sound output device in starcraft options, no luck. No matter what devices i set sound is playing from internal speakers as long as starcraft is launched. Sound is start to "route correctly" about 2 seconds after stracraft launch, so this made me think maybe starcraft have some library that make this trickery happens. Thanks for your thoughts, they give me new direction to think.

Comment: (1) Also check the bios setting regarding audio device, try enable and disable. (2) When playing SC2, check the `Control Panel-> Sound -> Playback` and see if the volume bar keep moving.

Comment: @JohnSiu (1) no settings conserning audio device in bios, no luck :( (2) volume bar on 1st device keep moving in SC2.

Comment: What about plying movie or music with media player?

Comment: @JohnSiu same as with all other sound. I even tried vlc, and used it audio redirection in file. File is ok i can listen it when "games" in background.

Answer (score 0):

If the sound is working in some apps and not others, there is in fact not a hardware problem with the system,  but a software problem. To prove this hypothesis, grab a copy of a live Linux distribution and stand in awe when all sound works in a completely different operating system. The problem is actually something in windows,  or a driver problem of some kind most definitely. Sounds like you need to reinstall the os if you ask me.

Comment: Sorry, but no. I tried debian(Ubuntu) and redhat(Fedora) linuxes kernels. No luck. No sound from internal speakers. I tried even very old alsa versions still dead.